# Cypher Query create multi relations

Tags: neo4j, cypher, relation

I am trying to create a generic query for creating relations between nodes.
The problem is when one match fail the other are ignored. The following query should create 3 relations. But it didn’t only 2. 
Thank you very much for your help. I am a beginer with Cypher
Vince

```
MATCH (a:Strata),(b) WHERE a.uid = 'strata60' AND b.uid= 'cmCharacteristic' CREATE (a)-[r:IS_CONSTITUTED_BY]->(b)

 WITH 1 as dummy 

 MATCH (a:Strata),(b) WHERE a.uid = 'strata60' AND b.uid= 'cloudCharacteristic' CREATE (a)-[r:IS_CONSTITUTED_BY]->(b) 

WITH 1 as dummy 

 MATCH (a:Strata),(b) WHERE a.uid = 'strata60' AND b.uid= '' CREATE (a)-[r:IS_CONSTITUTED_BY]->(b) 

WITH 1 as dummy 


 MATCH (a:Strata),(b) WHERE a.uid = 'strata60' AND b.uid= '' CREATE (a)-[r:IS_CONSTITUTED_BY]->(b) 

WITH 1 as dummy 

 MATCH (a:Strata),(b) WHERE a.uid = 'strata60' AND b.uid= 'mFeCharacteristic' CREATE (a)-[r:IS_CONSTITUTED_BY]->(b)

 WITH 1 as dummy 

 MATCH (a:Strata),(b) WHERE a.uid = 'strata60' AND b.uid= '' CREATE (a)-[r:IS_CONSTITUTED_BY]->(b)
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use `OPTIONAL MATCH` instead of `MATCH` on all subsequent ones. Then if those ones don't exist your query won't fail.

Answer (score 1):

A more generic query

```
match (a:Strata {uid: 'strata60'}), b where b.uid in ['x', 'cmCharacteristic']
with a, collect(b) as bs
foreach (b in bs | create unique a-[:REL]->b)
```

This will match only the `b` nodes which have a valid `uid` in the array given, and create a relation to each of them, so this will not fail if invalid `uid`s are in the list (they'll just be ignored).

The query will run if there is at least one valid `b`; else it will fail, which is ok, since no relation should be created anyway.